# Замена bower на другой пакет, какой выбрать?

Tags: javascript, node.js, bower

Есть какой то новый пакет такой же по функционалу как bower (полностью), но и имеет какие то новые функции. Замена bower на лучший пакет есть?

Comment: мне хватает npm

Comment: Можно рассматривать npm, как сказал @StrangerintheQ, можно посмотреть в сторону yarn или pnpm. А так вопрос, лучше закрыть, потому что на него невозможно дать один правильный ответ